# Space remaining on the right for smaller devices(mobile devices)

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, row, col

While viewing on laptop screen there is no space left on the right and there is no need to scroll to the right to view the content. But when I viewed the same for smaller (mobile) devices, theres a space left on the right side and there is a scrollbar to scroll to the right which I don't want.

PFB the code with issue arising unders comment block  :

```html
<!-- ========== MAIN CONTENT ========== -->
    <main id="content" role="main">

        <!-- Career Title Section -->
        <div class="container space-top-1 space-top-md-4">
            <div class="position-relative">
                <!-- Title -->
                <div class="w-md-80 w-lg-70 text-center mx-md-auto">
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <h2 class="h1 text-primary font-size-md-down-3"> <span class="font-weight-semi-bold">Photo
                                Gallery</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="text-dark">View the pictures
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Title -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Career Title Section -->


        <!-- FAQ Topics Section -->
        <div class="space-0 space-md-2  pl-2 pr-2 pl-lg-9 pr-lg-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-7 ">
                    Content 1 Card will be populated here
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    Content 2 Card will be populated here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End FAQ Topics Section -->


    </main>
    <!-- ========== END MAIN CONTENT ========== -->
```

PFB the screenshots on smaller device having space on the right.
[image]

But when I use container in the div, the issue gets resolved on small screens but it limits me with the padding space on the left & right. PFB the code below:

```html
<!-- ========== MAIN CONTENT ========== -->
    <main id="content" role="main">

        <!-- Career Title Section -->
        <div class="container space-top-1 space-top-md-4">
            <div class="position-relative">
                <!-- Title -->
                <div class="w-md-80 w-lg-70 text-center mx-md-auto">
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <h2 class="h1 text-primary font-size-md-down-3"> <span class="font-weight-semi-bold">Photo
                                Gallery</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="text-dark">View the pictures
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Title -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Career Title Section -->


        <!-- FAQ Topics Section -->
        <div class="container space-0 space-md-2  ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-7 ">
                    Content 1 Card will be populated here
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    Content 2 Card will be populated here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End FAQ Topics Section -->


    </main>
    <!-- ========== END MAIN CONTENT ========== -->
```

PFB the screenshot on smaller screens (mobile):
[image]

What could be the solution to this. How can I remove the space coming on the right to disappear. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You are probably looking for [`container-fluid`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers)

Comment: the code you posted isn't enough to demonstrate the issue.. can you post *all* of the relevant code

Comment: Thanks @Turnip. Now it's working fine